# how can I get R to read a string as a restriction?

Tags: string, r, restriction

Instead of writing for a vector V:

```
V[a>1 & b==2 & c<1]
```

I would like something like:

```
V[restriction]
```

with

```
restriction = "a>1 & b==2 & c<1"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks, 
F.

Comment: Are you looking for `eval(parse(text=restriction ))`? But you should create a reproducible example!

Comment: Say V is a vector 1:10;  a = -3:6; b = rep(1,2, length=10); c=-5:4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
> V <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5, c = 0)
> restriction = "a>1 & b==2 & c<1"
> subset(V, eval(parse(text = restriction)))
  a b c
2 2 2 0
```